# how to check same values from two diffrent objects with diffrent number of value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have these three objects with a different number of values I need to check if available values are the same in other Object. Like if I compare `obj1` with `obj2` then in `obj2` we have only two keys and in `obj1` we have the same keys with the same values then it returns `true` ... Please help me to write the function

Thanks in advance :)

```
const obj1 = { age: 25, color: "white", weight: true };
const obj2 =  { color: "white", weight: true }
const obj3 = { age: 26, color: "white", weight: true }

console.log(matches(obj1, obj2)); // true
console.log(matches(obj2, obj1)); // false
console.log(matches(obj3, obj1)); // false
console.log(matches(obj3, obj2)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :)

```
const obj1 = { age: 25, color: "white", weight: true };
const obj2 =  { color: "white", weight: true }
const obj3 = { age: 26, color: "white", weight: true }

function matches(obj1, obj2) {
const isValidKeyValuePair = (currentKey) => {
return obj2[currentKey] === obj1[currentKey];
};
return Object.keys(obj2).every(isValidKeyValuePair)
}

console.log(matches(obj1, obj2)); // true
console.log(matches(obj2, obj1)); // false
console.log(matches(obj3, obj1)); // false
console.log(matches(obj3, obj2)); // true
```